# How to stop text input affecting movement keys in BGE?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks, text-object

I have set up text input to give orders to npc, but it affects my first person character movement whenever they contain letters a,s,d and w, so how do I "disable" the movement while typing?

Answer (score 1):

> character movement whenever they contain letters a,s,d and w, so how
>   do I "disable" the movement while typing?

The same way you talk to your friends:
Before typing text tell the character to ignore whatever you type.

(Be aware you need to define a way to let the character know that it should stop ignoring your typing.)